# android, how to dispose the observer in case there is no context, or lifeCycle object

Tags: android, rx-java2

In android app and in the place there is no access to context and lifeCycle object, and this code is in independent class not live in fragment/activity/ViewMode, so no help from onDestroy()

what is the right way to dispose the observer?

it could add `.autoDispose(lifecycleOwner.scope())` if there is access to the `lifecycleOwner` but not able to in this case.

```
interface IUpdate {
        fun onUpdateComplete(isSuccess: Boolean, exception: Throwable?)
    }

fun updateTopic(data: Data, cb: IUpdate? = null) {
        var disposable: Disposable? = null
        disposable = dataRepository.updateDatabase(data) // this one returns a Completable, and actually go fetch from remote and update database, may take a bit time
            .compose(Transformers.completableIOToMain())
            //.autoDispose(lifecycleOwner.scope())//<=== no access to lifecycleOwner
            .subscribe({
                disposable?.dispose(). // <=== is it right to do here
                cb?.onUpdateComplete(true, null)
            }, {
                disposable?.dispose() // <=== is it right to do here
                cb?.onUpdateComplete(false, it)
            })
    }
```

Comment: Return a `Single` instead of subscribing in place

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce! Isnt he Single also need to be disposed? From what I read the Single is a Observable and should use a disposable.
Disposable d = Single.just("Hello World")
    .subscribeWith((), {}) 

 Thread.sleep(5000) 
 d.dispose()

Comment: As @EpicPandaForce mentioned, make `updateTopic` return a `Single` and move the `dispose`/`subscribe` to the presentation layer where you have access to the lifecycle owner. If you are using a `ViewModel`, the `onCleared` method would be the right place to dispose it.

Comment: that is problem, here the updateTopic is from 3rd part lib's interface define and implemented in our side which does not take return. no control on the returns.

Comment: Then you should make the method synchronously implemented and wrap it with RxJava with your own interface/class using `Single.fromCallable {}`

Comment: does doing `disposable?.dispose()` inside the subscribe({}, {}) callback cause any problem?     `.subscribe({
                disposable?.dispose() }, {...})`